# How to update an object's inner property from UI to VM? (WPF MVVM)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a property in my ViewModel, I'll call it "Project" which contains several nested lists inside of it. None of such lists has an associated property in the view model since I can show everything in xaml by using triggers and bindings.
My xaml shows the Project hierarchy in a treeview and its details in several views (a content control selects the right view depending on which item is selected on the treeview). One of those "details" is a property for the objects contained in one of the nested lists, I'm showing it in a textbox so the user can edit it, the problem I'm having is I don't see that property updated in the Project property in the VM once I make changes to it in the textbox.
I was told I have to create a property in the VM for that specific object's property I'm trying to edit, I just don't know how since the object is deep inside one of the nested lists of my Project object.

Comment: Can you share some of your code, so we have a better context?

Answer (score 0):

Common mistakes are:

**Using OneWay binding mode instead of TwoWay**

In XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Not realizing that the update is not propagated to the VM until after the TextBox lost focus.**

this is the default for the TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

You could change it to:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```